# How to run a specific test or class using jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, testing, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using this command to run my tests:

```
sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean test -e -Dgroups=categories.dbd"
```

but sometimes I want to run a specific test. How can I do it?

I read that I can use "This project is parameterized" but didn't understand how to use it.

I also saw this - https://plugins.jenkins.io/selected-tests-executor/ but it's not good enough since it required an external file.

---

Comment: Jenkins isn't really the tool for that. It's typical use case us running *all* tests. If you want to run only one test, you should do that in your development environment.

Comment: But there are differences between running the test on my local environment and running on the Jenkins server. And what about a specific class?

Comment: Why? it does not make any sense. my job can run over 1h and I don't want to wait this time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test) you can simply run

```
sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean test -e -Dgroups=categories.dbd -Dtest=com.example.MyJavaTestClass"
```

or

```
sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean test -e -Dgroups=categories.dbd -Dtest=com.example.MyJavaTestClass#myTestMethod"
```

I suggest to add a parameter for the test class/method to your pipeline definition.

```
pipeline {

  agent any

  parameters {
    string defaultValue: '', description: 'Test Name', name: 'TEST_NAME', trim: false
  }

  stages {
    stage('run tests') {
      steps {
        script {
          def optionalParameters = ""
          if (params.TEST_NAME != null) {
            optionalParameters += " -Dtest=" + params.TEST_NAME
          }
          sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn clean test -e -Dgroups=categories.dbd" + optionalParameters
        }
      }
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where should I set the TEST_NAME?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer and provided a complete pipeline definition.

Answer (score -3):

Jenkins isn't really the tool for that. It's typical use case us running *all* tests. If you *really* want to run only one test, you should do that in your development environment

But the simplest thing to do, if you want the results for one of the tests, us to have Jenkins run all your tests and simply  ignore the results for the other tests.

Generally, you should run (quick, cheap) unit tests in your development environment, and submit code for (expensive, slow) integration tests by Jenkins only once the code passes the unit tests (And Jenkins should run the unit tests again, just in case).

I suspect your real question is "how do I debug failure of an integration test run by Jenkins". Jenkins is a build and test tool  not a debugging tool. It is not itself a suitable tool for debugging test failures. But the way you use Jenkins can help debugging.

- Do not use integration tests as a substitute for unit tests.
- If your software fails an integration test, but no unit tests, as usual with debugging a test failure you should be making hypotheses about the kinds of defect in your software that could cause the failure. Then check whether a unit test could be added that would detect that kind of defect. If so, add that unit test.
- Ensure that your tests produce useful diagnostic messages on failure. Test assertions should have helpful messages. Test a should have descriptive names.
- If an integration test checks a sequence of actions, ensure you also have tests for the individual actions.